# Position something relative to the height of a div containing text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a button with a popup that appears beneath it when the user hovers over it.

The requirements are as follows:

- The Button's size is independent of the popup's size
- The popup is always a fixed distance from the bottom of the button
- The popup does not interfere with the position of any element (hence the absolute position)
- The popup is centered relative to the button

Here is an image to represent that. My current attempt then follows.

[image: represent]

```css
.button-container {
  display : inline-flex;
  height  : 100%;
  }
.popup-positioner {
  display  : inline-block;
  position : relative;
  right    : 50%;
  }
.button-container button {
  background-color : rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
  border           : none;
  border-radius    : 5px;
  outline          : 0px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);
  font-weight      : 900;
  color            : rgb(220, 220, 220);
  padding          : 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  }
.button-container .popup {
  display           : none;
  background-color  : rgba(80, 80, 80, 1);
  color             : rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
  border-radius     : 5px;
  -webkit-transform : translate(-50%, 110%);
  padding           : 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  }
.button-container:hover .popup {
  position  : absolute;
  display   : block;
  animation : show_popup 0.5s;
  }
@keyframes show_popup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 110%);
    }
  100% { 
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 110%);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="button-container">

  <button> 
      this is a button with lots of text
  </button>
  
  <div class"popup-positioner">
    <div class="popup"> 
      this is a popup
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Currently, my code performs the following:

[image: Current Operation]

This is the desired effect for this setup. The issue is, that the popup is being positioned relative to its own height.

```css
.button-container .popup {
    ...
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 110%);
    ...
}
```

This means that on smaller screens, I will get the following undesired behaviour:

[image: Bad]

I would like the popup to be positioned relative to the height if the `<button>` above it.
I would appreciate any help on how to do this.
Many thanks - Oli

Comment: Upgraded my answer's code to a more compact and efficient one. Hope this helps as another good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute positioning can be made with `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to position an element relative to a parent container. This is what your snippet is missing.

Additionally use `transition` over `animation` when doing hovers. They tend to be easier to work with when switching from state A to state B and vice versa.

In the snippet below I've put the `popup-positioner` at the bottom of the `button-container` and gave it a `padding-top`. This padding will be the spacing between the popup and the button and should be adjusted to your liking. This means that the space between the button and the popup will always be the same.

The reason to do it like described above is to ensure that when hovering the button, the popup won't disappear whenever you move your mouse from the button to the popup.

Use `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent senteces from wrapping. If you do need a line break in your sentence use a `<br>` tag to indicate where the sentence should break.

```css
.button-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.button-container button {
  background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: 0px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
}

.button-container .popup-positioner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 150ms ease-in-out;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
}

.button-container:hover .popup-positioner {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.button-container .popup {
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 1);
  color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button>this is a button with lots of text</button>
  <div class="popup-positioner">
    <span class="popup">this is a popup</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and quick workaround. Will always keep pop up under button and centered. Even if you don't know the width of the popup.

I created new Ids, but you can change it freely.

You can also use `display: none;` & then when hovering `display: block;` as an alternative to opacity.

```css
/* Set parent(button) container relative */

#button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Pop up position: absolute, left: 50% and translate back 50% based on the its width */

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


/* Just increase opacity of popup whenever parent(button) is hover */

#button:hover #popup {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button">
  <span>This is a button with lots of text. Text text, more text.</span>
  <span id="popup">Button Pop Up</span>
</a>
```